# The proxy for IE in Selenium is not specified after several successful attempts

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, proxy

maybe someone can tell why the proxy stops for IE after ~ 50 tests. At first everything works well, the proxy is successfully installed.

Selenium Standalone Server 3.141.59
Internet Explorer Driver Server x64 3.141.59 (x32 is the same)

Maybe my problem is described in this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2010/04/09/setwindowshookex-fails-with-error-error_mod_not_found/) ? If yes, how to free global hooks?

I looked at the driver logs and most likely an error in this:

```
T 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\proxymanager.cpp(97) ProxyManager::SetProxySettings
D 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\proxymanager.cpp(100) Setting proxy for individual IE instance.
T 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\proxymanager.cpp(244) ProxyManager::SetPerProcessProxySettings
T 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\proxymanager.cpp(147) ProxyManager::BuildProxySettingsString
D 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\proxymanager.cpp(180) Built proxy settings string: ‘http=localhost:6666 ftp=localhost:6666 https=localhost:6666’
T 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\hookprocessor.cpp(105) Entering HookProcessor::Initialize
T 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\hookprocessor.cpp(164) Entering HookProcessor::InstallWindowsHook
W 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\hookprocessor.cpp(187) [Windows Error 126]: Unable to set windows hook
T 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\hookprocessor.cpp(258) Entering HookProcessor::PushData
W 2019-05-04 15:21:59:208 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\hookprocessor.cpp(260) No hook procedure has been set
```

As I understand it, WindowsHook stops working, but why and how to fix it?

```cs
public override IWebDriver CreateRemoteDriver() {
    var options = GetOptions();

    return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(GridUri), options.ToCapabilities(), CommandTimeout);
}

public InternetExplorerOptions GetOptions() {
    InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions {
        IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
        InitialBrowserUrl = "about:blank",
        EnableNativeEvents = true,
        EnsureCleanSession = true,
        EnablePersistentHover = false,
        UsePerProcessProxy = true,
        ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
        BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private"
    };

    var str = GetStrategyValueOrNull();
    if (str != null) options.AddAdditionalCapability(PageLoadStrategyCapabilityName, str);

    foreach(var capability in CapabilityProperties) {
        options.AddAdditionalCapability(capability.Name, capability.Value);
    }

    var proxy = GetProxy();

    if (proxy != null) {
        options.Proxy = GetProxy();
    }
    return options;
}

public Proxy GetProxy() {
    if (Proxy != null) {
        var proxy = new Proxy {
            Kind = ProxyKind.Manual,
            IsAutoDetect = false,
            HttpProxy = Proxy,
            SslProxy = Proxy,
            FtpProxy = Proxy
        };
        return proxy;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you please inform us which OS you are using to make this test? Also try to check whether any setting or any configuration got changed on that machine or not. Check whether any new update affect the output or not.

Comment: I use selenium grid. I have 4 remote computers with the following operating systems: Windows 10, Windows 8.1 and Win Server 2016. All computers have the same behavior. Settings don't change

Comment: Maybe my problem is described in this  
[post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2010/04/09/setwindowshookex-fails-with-error-error_mod_not_found/) ? 

If yes, how to free global hooks?

Comment: To free the hook you can try to use UnhookWindowsHookEx function. This is the documentation link which you can try to refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unhookwindowshookex

Comment: To call the UnhookWindowsHookEx function, I don’t know the HHOOK receiving parameter

Comment: A handle to the hook to be removed. This parameter is a hook handle obtained by a previous call to SetWindowsHookEx.

Comment: The call to the SetWindowsHookEx function occurs in selenium iedriver code.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/cpp/iedriver/HookProcessor.cpp